# Java comparing two letters

Tags: java, loops, compare, back

I ran in to a small problem while working on my assignment. Basically I'm making a small program that asks the user for 3 letters and compares them to 3 letters that are coded in. Then the program is supposed to compare the 3 letters and if they're the same then print true. Thus far I've been able to make it without problems using `compareTo`, but now the tricky part is that I need to add a "tolerance" to the program (which I have) but the tolerance is supposed to loop back from Z to A. So if tolerance is 3 and the user inputs X Y Z (when it really is A B C) it should still print out true.

NOTE: the Tolerance will not go above 3. ALSO, We shouldn't use Arrays.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? If it's complicated to understand what I'm asking please post and I'll try to clarify it :)

Thanks

EDIT: basically this is the code that compares the tolerances

```
        if ((a1.compareTo(d1) <= tolerance) && (a1.compareTo(d1) >= negTolerance) 
        && (b1.compareTo(e1) <= tolerance) && (b1.compareTo(e1) >= negTolerance) 
        && (c1.compareTo(f1) <= tolerance) && (c1.compareTo(f1) >= negTolerance))
    {
        open = true;
    } else open = false;
```

where a1 - c1 are pre inputed characters and d1-f1 are user entered. tolerance is also user entered as an integer between 1 and 3

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, please add the tag "homework".

Comment: Could you include a table of testcases?  You mention that "X Y Z" should match "A B C" but I have no idea what should not match "A B C".

Comment: its a project, and tolerance is basically by how much the user can be off to still print out true

Comment: and x y z and a b c are just examples, basically the letters inputted have to be within the "tolerance" or error value of the letters coded in. Like between a and b the tolerance is 1, between g and m its 5. now i need it to be between a and z = 1, a and y = 2, a and x = 3, etc

Comment: Add your code, we can help you go over it.

Comment: it's a really long code, ill try to add only the part that i need this for

Comment: But what specifically is the tolerance? Is it the difference in ASCII between each letter in the sequence? What would the tolerance have to be for G V H to return true? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a homework assignment, I won't give you the full answer, but I'll give you a hint. You want to look at the character codes (ASCII) for the letters. This will let you solve the tolerance problem. You might also have to do some magic with `%` (modulus) to handle the looping back of Z to A.

**EDIT**

If you cannot use the ASCII values, the return value of `compareTo` will help you, but keep in mind that that comparing `A` to `Z` and `Z` to `A` will give you -25 and 25 respectively. This is where the `%` operator will help you.

Comment: well that's not the entire assignment, its just a very small part of it, but I thought of trying that but we never learned the use of ASCII in Java, so I can't really use it :(

Comment: Did your teacher specifically tell you that you cannot use ASCII values?

Comment: No, my prof did not say that but he wouldn't expect us to know it if we haven't learned it in the course yet. We haven't even done Arrays yet

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out without the %, using just simple if statements. Unfortunately I cannot answer my own question but in 7 hours ill post the method he most likely expects us to do.

basically 
if the comparing the 2 letters is 24(or -24), tolernace =1, and the same for 23 and 22

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the ASCII value of the char.

```
char[] expecteds = ...;
int tolerance = 3;
char input = ...;
int inputValue = char;

for (int i=0; i<expecteds.length; i++){ 
  int delta = expected[0] - 'a' - input - 'a' % 'a';
  if (i < tolerance)
      result = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Modulus (%) operator to cycle back around to the beginning:

```
int index = 0;
for (i in 1 .. 26) {
  int index = (i+tolerance) % 26;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Map each character to a Number
2) Grab the tolerance
3) Add/subtract the tolerance from the number
4) Compare the letters in the tolerance range to the letter
```

Comment: well I found it easier to grab the tolerance simply by doing char1.compareTo(char2). Except that means the difference between z and a is 25 instead of 1